# How to do cell coloring back and forth automatically in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I'd like to ask on how to do a cell coloring for the following case:
For example, I have an excel like this:

```
Col1 Col2
A    1
A    2
B    3
B    4
B    5
C    1
C    2
D    1
D    2
E    2
E    8
E    9
```

I want to make the cell color to be like this:

```
Col1 Col2
A    1   *cell color yellow*
A    2   *cell color yellow*
B    3   *cell color green*
B    4   *cell color green*
B    5   *cell color green*
C    1   *cell color yellow*
C    2   *cell color yellow*
D    1   *cell color green*
D    2   *cell color green*
E    2   *cell color yellow*
E    8   *cell color yellow*
E    9   *cell color yellow*
```

Is there a way to do it automatically, like using formula or something else? The real case has a lot of rows so I'm unsure about doing it manually.

The rule is based on Col1 values, so it will switch back and forth when the value in Col1 is changed. So if the first value is A, the color will be, for example, yellow, and then when it changes to B, the cell color will be changed to green for all cells with Col1 = B. Then, change back again to yellow when the value changes again. Simply, it's just switching cell color back and forth for each distinct value in Col1, no matter what the values is. The precondition is the table has already been sorted alphabetically based on Col1.

Comment: This sounds like conditional formatting would work. What is the rule that determines which color is used?

Comment: The rule is based on Col1 values, so it will switch back and forth when the value in Col1 is changed. So if the first value is A, the color will be, for example, yellow, and then when it changes to B, the cell color will be changed to green for all cells with Col1 = B. Then, change back again to yellow when the value changes again. Simply, it's just switching cell color back and forth for each distinct value in Col1, no matter what the values is. The precondition is the table has already been sorted alphabetically based on Col1.

Comment: For the answer, see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710984/excel-alternate-the-color-of-each-cell-change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want by using conditional formatting and the following formula:

```
  =MOD(ROUND(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A1<>"")/COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A$1:$A1&"")),0),2)=0
```

To set the conditional formatting, first select the entire range that you want to apply color to. Then choose Home / Conditional formatting / New Rule from the ribbon.

Then select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Enter this formula and then choose your formatting.

Go through the same process to set the contrasting color you want, but this time, end the formula with "=1" rather than "=0".

This answer is based on the accepted answer for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710984/excel-alternate-the-color-of-each-cell-change/12712011#12712011), modified to correct a rounding problem in that answer.